# Unable to build glibc

Tags: gcc, compiler-errors, compilation, gnu-make, glibc

I'm trying to build glibc 2.27 as a static library from sources on Ubuntu 18.04. This is the command I am using(after making a separate build directory for glibc):

```
$ git clone git://sourceware.org/git/glibc.git && cd glibc
$ git checkout release/2.27/master
$ cd ..
$ mkdir glibc-build && cd glibc-build
$ ../glibc/configure --enable-kernel=4.4 --disable-shared --enable-static --enable-static-nss --prefix=/usr
$ make
```

`make` results in this error:

```
cc1: fatal error: /home/parallels/glibc-build/libc-modules.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
../Makerules:281: recipe for target '/home/parallels/glibc-build/ucontext_i.h' failed
make[2]: *** [/home/parallels/glibc-build/ucontext_i.h] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/parallels/glibc/csu'
Makefile:215: recipe for target 'csu/subdir_lib' failed
make[1]: *** [csu/subdir_lib] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/parallels/glibc'
Makefile:9: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

[Full log for `make`](https://pastebin.com/0FWvcvGz)

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 and am using the preinstalled versions of `gcc` and `make`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a known issue:

- [Unable to build GLIBC with --disable-shared](https://sourceware.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=20845)

In general, this is not a problem because a default build (without `--disable-shared`) builds both the static and dynamically linked version of the library, and `make install DESTDIR=…` installs both.